# How do I turn of the trace information Erlang ftp prints to console?

Tags: ftp, erlang

The Erlang's (v.19) ftp client traces **everything** to console, including the full contents of file received. I open session with the default options (verbose is false etc.)

For example,

> {:ok, pid} = :inets.start(:ftpc, host: String.to_charlist(v.host))
>
> --ctrl #Port<0.33168> ----> 220---------- Welcome to Pure-FTPd [privsep] [TLS] ---------- 220-You are user number 2 of 50 allowed.
>   220-Local time is now 15:44. Server port: 21. 220-This is a private
>   system - No anonymous login 220-IPv6 connections are also welcome on
>   this server. 220 You will be disconnected after 15 minutes of
>   inactivity. {state,{tcp,#Port<0.33168>},
>          undefined,undefined,false,"/home/jf/projects/bedrock2",
>          ftp_server_default,false,passive,60000,<<>>,
>          {<<>>,[],start},
>          [],<0.395.0>,
>          {<0.395.0>,#Ref<0.0.1.7380>},
>          open,inet,ignore,infinity,false,false}    ...handle_ctrl_result({pos_compl,"---------- Welcome to Pure-FTPd
>   [privsep] [TLS] ----------\r\n220-You are user number 2 of 50
>   allowed.\r\n220-Local time is now 15:44. Server port: 21.\r\n220-This
>   is a private system - No anonymous login\r\n220-IPv6 connections are
>   also welcome on this server.\r\n220 You will be disconnected after 15
>   minutes of inactivity.\r\n"},...) ctrl_data={<<>>,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a problem in OTP 19, since if you look at [the `ftp.erl` source code at the `OTP-19.0` git tag](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/5c764919283a711474a11afe2b5bfeba49229a89/lib/inets/src/ftp/ftp.erl#L109-L110), you can see they accidentally left a debug macro enabled:

```
%%-define(DBG(F,A), 'n/a').
-define(DBG(F,A), io:format(F,A)).
```

This was later fixed in [commit c7478ca8](https://github.com/erlang/otp/commit/c7478ca8549817bb6b20bc0000edb1f00f6fdf6f#diff-64c59889ef07ae619ed8ba634ca554a8), which is part of [OTP 19.0.1](http://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-questions/2016-June/089665.html).